# Async function javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou a fazer uma API em Node.js e tenho uma função que chamo através do post, mas antes de encaminhar para o repositório preciso que execute a função `getProduto(idProd, produto)`, mas está a fazer o `console.log('produto -> '+ produto.nome);` antes de executar a função `getProduto(idProd, produto)`.

Não sei como fazê-lo esperar que a outra função termine. Já experimentei adicionar o `async` e o `await` , mas sem sucesso.

```
exports.postItemProduto = async function (req, res) {
    try {
        var idProd = req.body.produtoPrincipal;

        await getProduto(idProd, produto);

        console.log('produto -> '+ produto.nome);

       ...
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send({
            error: 'Erro criar item'
        });
    };
};

function getProduto(id, produto){
    ....
    console.log('getproduto -->' + produto.nome);
}
```

Comment: Mas o `getProduto` é assincrono ? Se sim também presisa de `async`

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 2):

`await` sempre aguarda o retorno de uma Promise, assinar a função `getProduto` para `async` irá sim garantir o retorno de uma Promise por essa, mas esse não é o seu problema e sim o código interno da função `getProduto`.

**1** Verifique se de dentro da função `getProduto`, você está retornando uma Promise de onde é recuperado o **Produto**.

Exemplo:

```
const getProduto = async (id, produto) => {
...
  console.log(`getproduto --> ${produto.nome}`);
  return repositorio.retornarProduto(id).then(prod => {id: prod.id, nome: prod.nome})
};
```

**2** Verifique se `getProduto` para recuperar o **Produto**, está processando uma função `callback`. Lembre-se, `await` aguarda uma Promise de retorno e `callback` executará paralelamente e será ignorado pelo `await` da função chamadora.

Exemplo fazendo um wrap de um `callback` para uma Promise:

```
const getProduto = async (id, produto) => {
...
  console.log(`getproduto --> ${produto.nome}`);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    repositorio.retornarProduto(id, function(produtoRetornado, erro){
       if(erro) reject(erro);
       else resolve(produtoRetornado);
    })
  });

};
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: não entendi porque fui negativado pelo que postei .. podemo me explicar?

Answer (score 0):

Pra utilizar o `await` você precisa fazer com que a função seja assíncrona. Para isso você pode utilizar o `async`:

```
const getProduto = async (id, produto) => {
  ...
  console.log(`getproduto --> ${produto.nome}`);
};

exports.postItemProduto = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { body: { produtoPrincipal: idProd } } = req;

    await getProduto(idProd, produto);

    console.log(`produto -> ${produto.nome}`);
    ...
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Erro criar item' });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Como toda função async retorna um Promise, você pode fazer:

```
exports.postItemProduto = function (req, res) {
    try {
        var idProd = req.body.produtoPrincipal;

        getProduto(idProd, produto).then(() => console.log('produto -> '+ produto.nome));

       ...
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send({
            error: 'Erro criar item'
        });
    };
};

async function getProduto(id, produto){
    ....
    console.log('getproduto -->' + produto.nome);
}
```